# Moment.js diff between UTC dates

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

I'm using [moments.js](http://momentjs.com/) for working with dates in javascript.  All dates are in UTC (or should be).

I have the following date (60 minutes from current time):

```
//Wed, 04 Apr 2012 21:09:16 GMT
to   = moment.utc().add('m', 60).toDate();
```

Now I want to get the difference in seconds between this date and the current UTC datetime, so I do:

```
seconds = moment.utc().diff(to, 'seconds');
```

This returns `10800` instead of `3600`, so 3 hours, instead of one.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

EDIT:

I updated the line to `seconds = moment().diff(to, 'seconds');` and it gets the currect seconds, but it's `-3600` instead of positive.

EDIT:

I now have these two moment objects:

```
{ _d: Thu, 05 Apr 2012 17:33:18 GMT, _isUTC: true }
{ _d: Thu, 05 Apr 2012 16:38:45 GMT, _isUTC: true }
```

d1 and d2.

When I do `d1.diff(d2, 'hours', true);` this returns `4`.  It's definitely something to do with UTC I think, but it seems this *should* work.

Answer (score 17):

This is a legitimate bug. I just filed it here: https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/261

To get around it, use the following instead.

```
var a = moment.utc().add('m', 60).toDate(),
    b = moment().diff(to, 'seconds'); // use moment() instead of moment.utc()
```

Also, if you need to get the `toString` of the date, you can use `moment().toString()` as it proxies to the wrapped `Date().toString()`

Comment: Just FYI, this was fixed in version 1.6.0.

Comment: The bug still exists when dealing with Summer Time. Example: Difference in days between 15/10/2017 and 22/10/2017 (UTC). First date is not in Brazilian Summer Time, but the second is. The fix you suggested above did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Might be time zones kicking in because you are using `toDate()`. Try to just work directly with moment (i.e. change it to `to   = moment.utc().add('m', 60);`).

Comment: Hm, that 'to' is really a value coming from the database, that was created using the code above, so I have to use toDate() to get the string to store.

Comment: @Super I edited the post.  Working with moment objects that are UTC, getting similar issues.